Where is the error in evaluating this series? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(4n^2-1)^2}$
Where is the error in evaluating this series? $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(4n^2-1)^2}$$
We have
$$
\frac{1}{n(4n^2-1)^2} 
= \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1} 
+ \frac{1}{2(2n-1)^2} - \frac{1}{2(2n+1)^2}, 
$$
so
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(4n^2-1)^2} 
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left({\frac{1}{2(2n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2(2n+1)^2}}\right) 
+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left({\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1}}\right) \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int^1_0 (x^{n-1} - x^{2n-2} - x^{2n})\,dx \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2} + \int^1_0 \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (x^{n-1} - x^{2n-2} - x^{2n})\,dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \int^1_0 \left(\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{1-x^2} - \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\right)\,dx \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2} + \int^1_0 \frac{x-x^2}{1-x^2}\,dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \int^1_0 \frac{x}{1+x}\,dx \\
&= \frac{3}{2} - \ln(2).
\end{align}
Therfore,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(4n^2-1)^2} = \frac{3}{2} - \ln(2).
$$
But using wolfram alpha :
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(4n^2-1)^2} = \frac{3}{2} - 2\ln(2).
$$
Where is the error?

Since you are using Wolfram alpha ... take each of the steps in your proof, evaluate with Wolfram, and see where the value changes.  That is the step with the error.

I will try to find out, thank you.

To do this properly, 1st series telescopes and the 2nd series partially telescopes. Leftover terms are like $2(1/n + 1/(n+2) + ... + 1/(2n)).$ The sum goes to $\ln 2,$ which you can see many ways, integral comparison among them.

If $N\in\Bbb N$ and $x\in[0,1]$, let$$f_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N(x^{n-1}-x^{2n-2}-x^{2n}).$$Then, for each $x\in[0,1]$,$$\lim_{N\to\infty}f_N(x)=\frac x{x+1}$$(in other words, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x^{n-1}-x^{2n-2}-x^{2n})=\frac x{x+1}$). However, the convergence is not uniform on $[0,1]$. It's easy to see why; it follows from the fact that, for each $N\in\Bbb N$, $f_N(1)=-N$. So, since the convergence is not uniform, you have no reason to assume (as you did) that$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^1f_N(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\lim_{N\to\infty}f_N(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Note that you did not need any computational tool in order to see that the value that you got is wrong. In fact, you got that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n+1}\right)=1-\log(2)>0,$$which is impossible since, for each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$\frac1n-\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n+1}=-\frac1{4n^3-n}<0.$$

Why $f_{N}(x)  $Convergence is not uniform ??

If $f(x)=\frac x{x+1}$, then $f(1)=\frac12$. Therefore, since $f_N(x)=-N$ for each $N\in\Bbb N$, the sequence $(f_N){N\in\Bbb N}$ doesn't even converge pointwise to $f$, since we don't have $\lim{N\to\infty}f_N(1)=f(1)$.

Thank you very much, Professor

As an alternative method
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left({\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}}\right)
=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac1n-1-2\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{2N+1}=$$
$$=1-\frac1{2N+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac1n-2\sum_{n=1}^{2N-1}\frac1{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac1{n}=$$
$$=1-\frac1{2N+1}+\frac1N+2\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac1n-2\sum_{n=1}^{2N-1}\frac1{n}$$
$$\sim 1+2\log(N-1)-2\log(2N-1)= 1+2\log\frac{N-1}{2N-1}\to 1-2\ln2$$
which leads to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(4n^2-1)^2} = \frac{3}{2} - 2\ln 2$.

An alternate and correct way to evaluate the sum is to write
$$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1} = \left(\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n-1}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right).$$  Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}.$$
Since
$$\frac{d^n}{dz^n}[\log(1-z)]_{z=0} = \left[ -\frac{(n-1)!}{(1-z)^n} \right]_{z=0} = -(n-1)!$$
and $\log(1-0) = 0$, we have
$$\log(1-z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-(n-1)!}{n!} z^n = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}.$$  This converges for $z = -1$, so
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = -\log(1-(-1)) = -\log 2,$$
and similarly,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+1} = 1 - \log 2.$$  Thus
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1} = 1 - 2 \log 2.$$

We can use Digamma function and Trigamma function
$$
\mathrm{I}=\sum_{\mathrm{n}=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\mathrm{n}\left( 4\mathrm{n}^2-1 \right) ^2}}
\\
\frac{1}{\mathrm{n}\left( 4\mathrm{n}^2-1 \right) ^2}=\frac{1}{\mathrm{n}}-\frac{1}{\left( 2\mathrm{n}+1 \right)}-\frac{1}{2\left( 2\mathrm{n}+1 \right) ^2}-\frac{1}{\left( 2\mathrm{n}-1 \right)}+\frac{1}{2\left( 2\mathrm{n}-1 \right) ^2}
\\
\mathrm{I}=-\mathrm{\varphi}\left( 1 \right) +\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{\varphi}\left( \frac{1}{2}+1 \right) -\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{4}\mathrm{\varphi}_1\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) -1 \right) +\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{\varphi}\left( 1-\frac{1}{2} \right) +\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{4}\mathrm{\varphi}_1\left( -\frac{1}{2} \right) -1 \right) 
\\
\,\, =\mathrm{\gamma}+\frac{1}{2}\left( 2-2\ln 2-\mathrm{\gamma} \right) -\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{\pi}^2}{2}-1 \right) +\frac{1}{2}\left( -2\ln 2-\mathrm{\gamma} \right) +\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{4}\left( \frac{\mathrm{\pi}^2}{2}+4 \right) -1 \right) 
\\
\,\,  =\left( 1-2\ln 2 \right) +\frac{1}{2}
\\
\,\,  =\frac{3}{2}-2\ln 2
$$
